# XmlDocument - How to get all values from multiple nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

Here is my sample XML file:

```
<Main>
    <Person>
        <Name>Božena</Name>
        <Surname>Němcová</Surname>
        <Gender>Female</Gender>
        <OrderNum>18</OrderNum>
        <BirthDate>04.02.1820</BirthDate>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Name>Jan</Name>
        <Surname>Žižka</Surname>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <OrderNum>7</OrderNum>
        <BirthDate>19.09.1360</BirthDate>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Name>Che</Name>
        <Surname>Guevara</Surname>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <OrderNum>27</OrderNum>
        <BirthDate>14.06.1928</BirthDate>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Name>Antonie</Name>
        <Surname>de Saint-Exupéry</Surname>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <OrderNum>15</OrderNum>
        <BirthDate>29.06.1900</BirthDate>
    </Person>
</Main>
```

Here is a code which I want to use to get a list of all values of **Name** element:

```
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load("PersonWrite.xml");
        XmlNodeList data = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("Main/Person/Name");
```

The problem is that I'm only getting a value from the first **Person** element.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. After loading the XML in the question, the result of `SelectNodes` is a list with 4 elements. Check how you're actually using `data`, and whether `PersonWrite.xml` really contains what you think it contains.

Comment: The continue of code is only `Console.WriteLine(data.Count);`, which is giving "1".

Comment: Then `PersonWrite.xml` does not contain what you think it contains. Check the result of `Path.GetFullPath("PersonWrite.xml")` and/or supply a full path in the `.Load`, and verify the file contains no unprintable or control characters that might gum up the works somehow. [Fiddle to verify](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d3Kfuw).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like using deserialisation, it's a lot easier to work with.

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

public class Main
{
    [XmlElement("Person")]
    public Person[] People { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public int OrderNum { get; set; }

    public string BirthDate { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var xmlString = @"<Main>
                        <Person>
                            <Name>Božena</Name>
                            <Surname>Němcová</Surname>
                            <Gender>Female</Gender>
                            <OrderNum>18</OrderNum>
                            <BirthDate>04.02.1820</BirthDate>
                        </Person>
                        <Person>
                            <Name>Jan</Name>
                            <Surname>Žižka</Surname>
                            <Gender>Male</Gender>
                            <OrderNum>7</OrderNum>
                            <BirthDate>19.09.1360</BirthDate>
                        </Person>
                        <Person>
                            <Name>Che</Name>
                            <Surname>Guevara</Surname>
                            <Gender>Male</Gender>
                            <OrderNum>27</OrderNum>
                            <BirthDate>14.06.1928</BirthDate>
                        </Person>
                        <Person>
                            <Name>Antonie</Name>
                            <Surname>de Saint-Exupéry</Surname>
                            <Gender>Male</Gender>
                            <OrderNum>15</OrderNum>
                            <BirthDate>29.06.1900</BirthDate>
                        </Person>
                    </Main>";

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Main));
        Main main = null;

        using (var reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
        {
            main = (Main)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        if (main == null)
        {
            return; 
        }

        Console.WriteLine(main.People.Length);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
4
```

Comment: Well, this is the way I wanted to create. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would go through the Child Nodes of Main Node

```
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load("PersonWrite.xml");
    XmlNodeList root = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("Main");
    foreach (XmlNode xnode in root.ChildNodes)
    {
       //get data from xnode
    }
```